# JQuery. $.post request .done() .fail() avoid code duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a post request like

```
  $.post("test", {
    ajax: "true",
    action: ""
  }).done(function(data){
    if (data == "ok"){
        //xxx
    } else if (data == "err"){
        //yyy
    }
  }).fail(function(){
    //yyy
  });
```

How to avoid code duplication in the post request if code in .done() method (comment 'yyy') the same in fail method (comment 'yyy') ??

Comment: If the server is yours, why not just send a different HTTP header on error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [always](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback method, and the request will always go in that block. As you know when data contains error and not, this method will work for server-side errors. And you can catch client-side errors by defining the final else block.

```
$.post("test", {
    ajax: "true",
    action: ""
}).always(function(data){
    if (data == "ok"){
        //xxx
    } else if (data == "err"){
        //handle server-side errors
    } else {
        //handle client-side errors like 404 errors
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get `data=="err"` when the request fails.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `data=="err"` is for when the request fails at the server side, not client. Exactly like @JanDvorak said.

Comment: you're right. data == 'err' will work for server side errors. I added the last else block to catch client-side errors.

Answer (score 8):

The most obvious and simple solution would be to simply have a failure callback like so:

```
function ajaxFailed() {
    // yyy
}

$.post("test", {
    ajax: "true",
    action: ""
}).done(function(data){
    if (data == "ok"){
        //xxx
    } else if (data == "err"){
        ajaxFailed();
    }
}).fail(ajaxFailed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have them call the same function, e.g.

```
function onErr() { 
    //yyy
}
$.post("test", {
    ajax: "true",
    action: ""
}).done(function(data){
    if (data == "ok"){
        //xxx
    } else if (data == "err"){
        onErr();
    }
}).fail(onErr);
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a slightly different solution. What if I have a few post requests, and error handling will be a little different. I would not want to create a new function for each error handling.

Comment: @ИгорьСлипко You have to create a new function anyways, named or not.  -- PS: please change your name to start with something that I have on my keyboard. It's hard to notify you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to change the protocol slightly, and make use of the [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) to indicate success or failure:

```
if($sqlError){
  header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service unavailable");
}
```

...

```
.done(function(){
   //xxx
}).fail(function(){
   //yyy
});
```